# Confusion about the definition of indefinite integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

let $f$ be a function and $\frac{d}{dx} F= f$. We know $\int f(x) dx=\{F(x)+c\colon c\in \mathbb R\}$, that is, it is  a set it is not one element. Also, we if $A$ is a set and $A+A=\{a+b\colon a,b\in A\}$ so $A+A\neq 2A.$ Consider the following problem $A:=\int e^x \sin(x) dx$, so we have
$$A=-e^x \cos(x)+e^x\sin(x)-A$$ and $$2A= -e^x \cos(x)+e^x\sin(x).$$ I have seen this solution in many books, maybe you do so. Based of my understanding of the indefinite integral as a set so the above integral is not correct. Any thought?

Comment: Can you explain how you got the equality $A=-e^x \cos(x)+e^x\sin(x)-A$?

Comment: The answer gives you one of the functions in the set, the rest of the functions can be obtained by adding a constant.

Comment: You have a typo where you've swapped $f$ and $F$. On a given domain, if $F$ is **an** antiderivative of $f$, then $f$ is the derivative of $F$, i.e. $f = \frac{d}{dx} F$. Notice that if $G$ is any other antiderivative, then an important corollary of the Mean Value Theorem is that $F$ and $G$ differ by a constant. That is $G(x) = F(x) + C$ for some real number $C$. The indefinite integral finds the set of all such functions, equivalently, all such vertical shifts of $F$ by $C$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I believe that's a double integration by parts. Which means the confusion here is what $\int f dg$ represents in the indefinite integration by parts formula $\int f dg = fg - \int g df$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, as I  did the integration by part twice.

Comment: @SammyBlack, Perhaps, why we added $A+A$ as $A$ which is not true.

Comment: When you are manipulating indefinite integrals, you are not manipulating sets of functions. Instead, you are computing with a particular antiderivative, knowing that in the end any particular antiderivative will completely determine the family of all antiderivatives. You are not adding two sets of antiderivatives when you do that calculation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I know but in this case, I did not specify any antiderivative I just added them.   This is not my solution I have seen this in many books but in books, they wrote the integral sing instead of the set.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether you specify or not. The same symbol  may mean different things, and here, the $+$ between the two indefinite integrals does not mean "add them term-by-term". So $\int e^x\sin x\,dx + \int e^x\sin x\,dx$ does not mean "add each element of the left set with each element of the right set". These are families of antiderivatives, and they are not added like we *sometimes* add sets of numbers.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Agreed, But why we have $A+A=2A$ based on what?

Comment: Based on "that's how you define the sum of two indefinite integrals of the same function". Based on $2\int f\,dx = \int 2f\,dx = \int (f+f)\,dx = \int f\,dx + \int f\,dx$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, you are completely right i really forgot that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that in the case where $A$ is a set of functions all of which differ from each other by a constant, $A + A = 2A$ is actually true.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I was wondering if this kind of explanation should be given to the calculus students when they start learning the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\int e^x\sin x\,dx + \int e^{x}\sin x\,dx = 2\int e^x\sin x\,dx$ is a consequence of the linearity of the integral.
$$\begin{align*}
\int e^x\sin x\,dx + \int e^x\sin x\,dx &= \int (e^x\sin x + e^x\sin x)\,dx\\
&= \int 2e^x\sin x\,dx,\\
&= 2\int e^x\sin x\,dx.
\end{align*}$$
Even if you want to interpret the indefinite integral as a set, you still get the right "answer": the functions are of the form $F(x)+C$ with $F$ fixed and $C$ a constant, and we if we add a function of the form $F(x)+C$ with a function $F(x)+D$ wee get $2F(x)+(C+D)$; that is, the elements of $A+A$ really are "take the fixed function $F(x)$, multiply it by two, and add a constant", i.e., $2A$.